# How to abbreviate names using regex?

Tags: r, regex

I was wondering if is possible to do this abbreviation?

```
t <- "CERVANTES CASA,JORGE LUIS"
```

The desired outcome is:

```
CERVANTES, JL
```

Approach:

```
> sub("\\s.+,", ", ", t)
[1] "CERVANTES, JORGE LUIS"
```

My problem is that since I have a long list of names, How can I make the substitution return the first letter of the last two names? Considering that the characters are different from one string to the other. Example:
For "JORGE", J; and for LUIS, "L".

Comment: How could you get `CERVANTES, JORGE LUIS` as output if you do not have `LUIS` in the example string? Could you please explain what input you may have?

Comment: also what happened to the "casa"`

Comment: Try with *stringr* `str_replace_all(t, "\\s[^,]*,\\s*(\\p{L})\\p{L}*(?:\\s+(\\p{L})\\p{L}*)?$", ", \\1\\2")`

Comment: TX, Indeed I made a typo in the example is corrected now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew mind explaining this regex? Also you should post probably post it.

Comment: It matches a whitespace, then 0+ chars other than `,`, then a comma, again 0+ whitespaces, captures a letter and then matches the rest of the word, and then matches an optional sequence of 1+ whitespaces, another  letter (that is captured into Group 2) and then 0+ letters up to the end of string. I am not sure it is what OP needs though.

Comment: This works neatly, but I don't completely get how it works... Indeed the outcome is what I intended.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, pretty nifty

Comment: @Haboryme: I posted as an answer since it works for OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
> library(stringr)
> t <- "CERVANTES CASA,JORGE ANTONIO"
> str_replace_all(t, "\\s[^,]*,\\s*(\\p{L})\\p{L}*(?:\\s+(\\p{L})\\p{L}*)?$", ", \\1\\2")
[1] "CERVANTES, JA"
```

See the [pattern online demo](https://regex101.com/r/41Gupz/1).

The **regex pattern** matches

- `\\s` - a whitespace, then
- `[^,]*` - 0+ chars other than `,`, then
- `,` -  a comma,
- `\\s*` - again 0+ whitespaces,
- `(\\p{L})` - captures a letter and then
- `\\p{L}*` - matches the rest of the word, and then
- `(?:\\s+(\\p{L})\\p{L}*)?` - matches an optional sequence of:

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces,
  - `(\\p{L})` - another letter (that is captured into Group 2) and then
  - `\\p{L}*`  - 0+ letters up to the end of string. I am not sure it is what OP needs though.
- `$`  - end of string

The **replacement** pattern:

- `,`   - a comma and a space
- `\\1\\2` - two backreferences to Group 1 and 2 inserting the contents matched with the 2 groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the next steps to obtain the desired abbreviations in a data frame:

First: Data sample:

```
Name<- as.data.frame(("CERVANTES CASA,JORGE ANTONIO"))
colnames(Name)<-"Name"
```

Second: Divide the names in two columns (comma is the delimiter):

```
df2<-as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(Name$Name, ",", 2))
colnames(df2)<-c("Last_Name", "Name")
```

Third: Extract first word of Last Name:

```
df2$First_LastName <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", df2$Last_Name)
```

Fourth: Extract first letter from name:

```
df2$First_Letter_Name<- substr(df2$Name, 1, 1)
```

Join the desired words in one column:

```
df2$desired <- paste(df2$First_Last_Name,",",df2$First_Letter_Name )
output in new column: CERVANTES , J
```

Comment: TX, Indeed I made a typo in the example is corrected now.

Comment: Do not worry. I hope its help you.